# ffmpeg: reencode and re-stream a network stream at lower bitrate

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming

I often find streams on the internet that are high-bitrate only, or video streams that offer no audio-only stream.

Is there a generic way to tell `ffmpeg` or `ffserver`, in my case on a small server, to input a given stream, digest it (reencode, ie. `x264`ify it or even HEVCify it, and convert the audio to AAC+ HEC at a low bitrate) and output
a) a lightweight low-bitrate version or
b) an audio-only stream of the ingested stream
that can be viewed (in my case) by a mobile device that doesn't have the greatest connectivity?

Thanks for any pointers in the right direction.